# How to use Embassy-Phylipnew in Python

Tags: biopython

I already installed ***embassy-phylipnew*** in my system. And I'm figuring out how to use it in python. Bad thing that there's no documentation I can find.

Does anyone know how to use it? I'm trying to use this to perform Phylip's dnadist and neighbor in commandline.

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation:

http://emboss.sourceforge.net/apps/cvs/embassy/phylipnew/

If you want to use it from python you'll have to use a command line interface like the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module. Biopython makes it easy to read the `fneighbor` output format (Newick) with the code at `Bio.Phylo`.